# Rewrite rule can't get the ID from rewrited

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I use this simple rule :

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^product/([0-9]+)-([^/]+)?$',
    'index.php?pagename=product&id=$matches[1]&slug=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
```

It works, it redirects to the correct page I have created, but I can't get the id param, I tried in the template of my page :

```
global $wp_query;

// undefined index
var_dump($wp_query->query_vars['id']);
```

I want my URL to be like this :

```
http://example.com/product/324-example-of-slug
```

Dunno if it's possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you need to add the `id` param to the list of public query variables :

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'query_vars');
function query_vars($public_query_vars)
{
    $public_query_vars[] = 'id';
    return $public_query_vars;
}
```

Thanks to this plugin for the help : https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/#reviews